# How do I get a function from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code :

```
function foo()
{
    alert(1);
}

var str = foo.toString();

var fn = Function(str); 

console.log(fn2.toString());
```

The output is :

```
function anonymous() {
 function foo()
 {
     alert(1);
 }
}
```

I am trying to get back the foo function and store it in fn .
But here the foo function is inside an Anonymous function.
I tried eval() . But it creates the foo function in global scope.

How do I get back the function from its stringified form ?

**UPDATE:**
I am creating a map of functions to arguments.
To uniquely identify the functions, I used toString() method.

```
var map[foo.toString()] = [1,2,3]; //this list is populated dynamically in my code

// Now I want to call foo with [1,2,3] as arguments. For this I need to get back foo() function
foo(1,2,3)
```

**UPDATE 2 :**
I solved this problem in a different way.
Essentially I wanted to create a map of (function) --> (arguments)
Here is the link to the related question :
[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247772/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-map-of-functions-to-arguments).

Comment: What is the need for that? ohh and _"I tried eval()"_ **Don't!** if you need to use `eval` you're doing something wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You looking for the ability to dynamically edit a function?

Comment: Why stringify the function at all?

Comment: I am using the string as the key for a hashtable. Later, I want to convert it back to call the function.

Comment: Your name and current problem are fitting. (just saying).

Comment: Then why not include a reference to the function itself in the table?

Comment: If you are storing a function and some arguments, I suggest using `Function.prototype.bind()`, which will give you a function pre-bound to those specific arguments.  Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: `var map = {}; map['foo'] = foo.bind(1,2,3); map['foo']();`

Comment: @Shmiddty The first parameter for `bind` sets `this`, so just `.bind(1,2,3)` probably isn't what the OP wants

Comment: Shh it's still early.

Comment: `var map = {}; map['foo'] = foo.bind({},1,2,3); map['foo']();`

Comment: @svidgen If I use the function directly as the key, it is implicitly converted to string. So , when I get the key back later in my code it is a string.I still need the conversion part.

Comment: @Shmiddty Haha I know you knew, I just wanted to point it out :)

Comment: @gdoron I just found that everyone out there is discouraging eval(). Thanks for the alert !

Comment: @FacePalm Yep. You can store the function as a value though -- use a separate, parallel structure if you must. Better than taking the parsing/compiling hit every time you use the function!

Comment: `eval` wouldn't create the function in the global scope, unless you're executing `eval` in that scope.

Comment: @amnotiam I assume this is what you meant; but to clarify: `eval` will create the function whereever you tell it to. E.g., `var x = function() { eval("var y = function() { console.log('hi there'); }"); y(); }` will create a function `x()` with a private function `y()` that writes to the console. If you want to attach the function to an object from outside the object, something like `eval('object.x = ' + fn);` does the trick;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this

```
function foo()
{
    alert(1);
}

var str = foo.toString();

var fn = Function('return ' + str)(); 


console.log(fn.toString());
```

In essence the Function() will try not to pollute the global scope, that's why it adds the function in its own scope; thus its wrapped in an anonymous function

Comment: @FacePalm Not much different than using `eval` though, if you were trying to avoid that.

Comment: *"In essence the Function() will try not to pollute the global scope, that's why it adds the function in its own scope; thus its wrapped in an anonymous function..."* It doesn't wrap the code in a function in an effort to protect the global scope. I mean it does do that, but that's not the point. `Function()` is a constructor for creating function objects. That's why it returns a function... because making functions is what the Function constructor does. You can also define parameters.

Comment: @svidgen i'm not really sure what you mean by that

Comment: @amnotiam yeah you're right, i just wanted to point out that that is the result of using Function, rather its intention. But, you're, i didn't put it correctly

Comment: @ppoliani Two reasons to avoid `eval`: 1) It allows arbitrary code execution [if used carelessly]. 2) It's slow -- introduces an additional parsing step. While I'm not as vehemently opposed to `eval` as most other folks, the OP should be aware that the `Function` constructor introduces the same concerns.

Comment: @ppoliani To be perfectly clear though, I don't believe `eval` is *always* an indicator that you're doing something you shouldn't be. (Only 99.99% of the time) In any event, it's not the huge security concern it's made out to be. If you're executing user-supplied or dynamically generated code, `eval` and `Function` are likely the least commonly used channels to do so. Devs mistakenly feel safer using tings like like `setTimeout` or linking directly to another site's script, even though the security concern is the same, if not worse.

Comment: @svidgen no am not saying that eval or Function is the best practice to use; In terms of security, as you you said, it might be risky when you evaluate user supplied data, which i think FalmPalm doesn't.  
Well apparently there would be a performance overhead due to double evaluation. In any case, i think it's up to developer to decide whether he follows the good practices of each language.
I personally, wouldn't do it that way

Comment: @ppoliani Sure. And I don't mean to criticize your answer. (It solves the OP's problem, after all!) The OP simply indicated in a previous comment that they'd found "corroborating" advice not to use `eval`, which I, perhaps mistakenly, assumed meant it and its "cohorts" should be avoided. I just wanted to make it clear that supplying a string to the `Function` constructor carries the same concerns. No criticism to your answer intended, though.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `var fn = foo;`? You should never need to convert a function to a string except maybe for debugging purposes.

Comment: That sir looks like a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

While I obviously don't know your full context, I would tend to agree that you should probably never need to "stringify" a function in JavaScript like this.

There is probably a better approach, based on what I interpreted as your main objective:

> I am creating a map of functions to arguments.

There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use **the function names themselves** as keys.

Here's a quick example:

```
function foo(x) {
  alert(x);
}

function bar(y) {
  alert(y);
}

var args = {
  foo: [1],
  bar: [2]
};

// Now call each function w/ the desired arguments:
for (var funcName in args) {
  window[funcName].apply(window, args[funcName]);
}
```

Obviously you would replace `window` above with whatever scope your functions are defined in (if applicable).