# What is the most efficient way to create map of functions to arguments?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a map of functions to its argument. This map will be updated dynamically. Finally all the functions will be called with their corresponding arguments.

```
function foo1(x) { 
    //do something with x
}

function foo2(x) { 
    //do something else with x
}

var map = {};
map[foo1] = [1,2,3];  //this array is updated dynamically in my code
map[foo2] = [4,5,6];

// I want to call foo1 and foo2 with their [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] arguments respectively.
```

I tried 2 approaches :

- Converted `foo1` to string (using `toString()` method) as the key for the map. Then later I get back the function from this string using Function constructor. But I am afraid if this will hit the performance.

```
// This works. But concerned about the performance

map[foo1.toString()] = [1,2,3];

for(i in map){
    var fn = Function( 'return '+ i)();
    fn(map[i]);
}
```

- Store objects that wrap up function and their respective arguments like:

```
   { fn : foo1 , args : [1,2,3] }
   { fn : foo2 , args : [4,5,6] }
```

Here I store the references to functions instead of the entire function definition. But I have to traverse through the entire array to add more arguments.

Is there any better approach to maintain this map? What are the drawbacks in the above mentioned approaches?

**UPDATE**

Answer to the question "in what situation I will need this" :

I am maintaining a map from arguments to functions. I update it dynamically.
Later in my code I want to create a reverse map and call the functions with all its arguments.

For eg :

```
1 -> foo1
2 -> foo2
3 -> foo1,foo2
4 -> foo1
... and so on.
```

Then I want to create a reverse map like this :

```
foo1 -> [1,3,4...]
foo2 -> [2,3,...]
```

And finally call :

```
foo1( [1,3,4...])

foo2( [2,3,...])
```

Comment: What is your overall goal? I can't think of a situation that would call for something like this.

Comment: Don't forget functions can have properties. You could always store the functions in an array, and attach their index in the array to the function as a propery, and look them up that way.

Comment: @DaggNabbit, That's basically a variant of the solution I posted ;)

Comment: Just something for you to be aware of, some mobile browsers (no clue which ones at this point), possibly some other JS engines, don't have a proper `toString()` on functions, so `anyFunction.toString()` will always equal the exact same thing (something like `function(){ [native code] }`) and your code will fall apart

Comment: @DaggNabbit Brilliant ! Bull's eye. My solution is closer to your suggestion.

Comment: @FacePalm, glad it helped :) I'd be interested in seeing what you ended up with if you feel like making an answer out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until there's a native cross-browser solution for having objects as keys, you could always implement your own solution. Here's an example of what you could do. In the code below, the `ObjectMap` will store a generated key as a `property` of the `object` that needs to serve as a `key`. The `property` name that is used to store the `key` on the `object` is randomized to reduce possible conflicts. The map implementation can then use this `property`'s `value` to retrieve the `key` on the `object` and then retrieve it's associated `value`.

**JSPERF: http://jsperf.com/object-map**

```
function ObjectMap() {
    this.key = 0;
    //you should implement a better unique id algorithm
    this.mapId = '_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    this.data = {};
}

ObjectMap.prototype = {
    set: function (object, value) {
        var key = ++this.key;

        if (object[this.mapId]) {
            return;
        }

        object[this.mapId] = key;
        this.data[key] = value;
    },

    get: function (object) {
        var key = object[this.mapId];

        return key? this.data[key] : null;
    },

    remove: function (object) {
        var key = object[this.mapId];
        if (!key) {
            return;
        }
        delete this.data[key];
        delete object[key];
    }
};

function a() {}

var map = new ObjectMap();

map.set(a, 'test');

console.log(map.get(a)); //test
```

Answer (score 3):

Objects in JavaScript can only have strings as keys, so using `map[foo1]` is practically identical to `map[foo1.toString()]`. These both have problems that you haven't noticed: they discard closed-over variables, e.g.:

```
function makeCounter() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function() { return ++counter; }
}
```

If I have

```
var myCounter = makeCounter();
```

then `myCounter.toString()` will be `function() { return ++counter; }`, and trying to reconstitute that with the `Function` constructor will result in having the wrong `counter` reference.

Really, the best option might be to use the function's name as the property and as a value, use an object like you suggested:

```
var map = {};
map['foo1'] = { fn: foo1, args: [1, 2, 3] };
```

Then, if you want to add more arguments later, it's pretty obvious:

```
map['foo1'].args.push(4);
```

And to call them all, you might use something like this:

```
for(var functionName in map) {
    if(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, functionName)) {
        continue;
    }
    map[functionName].fn.apply(null, map[functionName].args);
}
```

Comment: Will there be any conflict if 2 functions from different scope have the same name ?

Comment: @FacePalm: Yes, unfortunately. If that's unacceptable, you'll have to use your solution with the array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use objects (or functions) as keys you'll need to use Harmony (EcmaScript 6) `WeakMap` or `Map`.  They're both currently experimental and both are available in Firefox. I believe `WeakMap` might also be available in Chrome (with the proper flag settings?).

If your platform supports WeakMap, and you choose to incorporate them, then their usage is quite straightforward:

```
var myWeakMap=new WeakMap();
myWeakMap.get(key [, defaultValue]);
myWeakMap.set(key, value);
myWeakMap.has(key);
myWeakMap.delete(key);
myWeakMap.clear();
```

More information (note the MDN references appear to be unlisted):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
- http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:weak_maps

Also: Alternatively you can use an array of functions, then use indexOf to get the index of the function, then access the parameters in an another array with that index.

```
function a(){}
function b(){}
var x=[a,b].indexOf(b);  //x=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Credits to Dagg Nabbit for suggesting this in the comments under my question.

> "Don't forget functions can have properties. You could always store the
>   functions in an array, and attach their index in the array to the
>   function as a propery, and look them up that way." - Dagg Nabbit

Consider the following map of **args-to-callback** arguments :

map :

```
1 -> foo1
2 -> foo1,foo2
3 -> foo2
```

The objective is to construct a **callback-to-args** map (reverse map) like this :

callbackMap:

```
foo1 -> [1,2]
foo2 -> [2,3]
```

Approach :

```
var allArgsPossible = [1,2,3]

// contains the list of callbacks to be called
var callbackArray = [];  

//maps the callback index in callbackArray to the callback's arguments
//callbackMap[index] = args means callbackArray[index] will be called with parameter "args" 
var callbackMap = {};

for( i in allArgsPossible)
{
    var item = allArgsPossible[i];
    var callbacks =  map[ item  ];
    for(j in callbacks)
    {
        var callback = callbacks[j];

        if(callback.index == undefined)
        {
            var index = callbackArray.length;
            // adding a new property "index" to the callback
            callback.index = index;
            callbackMap[index] = [item];
            //create a new entry in callbackArray
            callbackArray.push(callback);
        }
        else
        {
            callbackMap[callback.index].push(item);
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(callbackMap));

for( i in callbackArray)
{
    var callback = callbackArray[i];
    //get arguments from our reverse map
    var args = callbackMap[callback.index];
    // Bingo ! 
    callback(args);
}
```

You can get the whole picture here : http://jsfiddle.net/kyvUA/2/

One point to note here is that the callback function may already have an "**index**" property for some other purpose. If that is a concern, you can generate a random string and store this property on the callback with the index as the value. ( as suggested by @plalx )

Cheers !